# Search entire database in mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi there I am writing one simple script to search from the entire database depending on the user input.
Here is my code :

```
<?php
$search=isset($_POST['search']);
$submit=isset($_POST['submit']);
if($submit){
$connect=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($connect,'go-web');
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT *  FROM `go-web`.`product` WHERE (CONVERT(`name` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`category` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`brand` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`keyword` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%')");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
echo '<tr><td style="height=100px"><center><a href=""><img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a><center><figcaption>Price:'.$row['price'].'</figcaption></center><br> <center><figcaption>Stock:'.$row['stock'].'</figcaption></center></center></td></tr>';
}
}
?>
```

The problem here is whenever i am giving the input i am getting the same result again and again.
Any help?
Thank you in adance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `$search = isset($_POST['search'])`, which will result in a boolean, then go on to use that in your query: `name LIKE '%$search%'`

```php
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']);

if(isset($search)) {

    $connect = new mysqli("localhost","root","","go-web");

    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $search);

    $sql = "SELECT *  FROM `go-web`.`product` WHERE (CONVERT(`name` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`category` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`brand` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%' OR CONVERT(`keyword` USING utf8) LIKE '%$search%')";

    $query = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo '<tr><td style="height=100px"><center><a href=""><img src="'.$row['image'].'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a><center><figcaption>Price:'.$row['price'].'</figcaption></center><br> <center><figcaption>Stock:'.$row['stock'].'</figcaption></center></center></td></tr>';
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: @SANTOSHVERMA please select the answer if it helped you solve your problem